# Explanation of stack overflow when using read on a small file and a questionable workaround

Tags: c, linux, stack-overflow

I hope the question explained my problem. I would also be grateful if the workaround that "works" is explained.

The traditional way of reading a file (that i  know of)

```
int fd;
char buffer[MAX];
while(read(fd,buffer,MAX)>0)
{
         buffer[MAX]='\0';
         write(sockfd,buffer,MAX);
         memset(buffer,NULL,MAX);
}
```

was causing an overflow. The workaround that somehow unexpectedly worked was

```
   while((read(fd,buffer,MAX)!=0)||(read(fd,buffer,MAX)!= -1))
   {
         buffer[MAX]='\0';
         write(sockfd,buffer,MAX);
         memset(buffer,NULL,MAX);

   }
```

^^ This code printed out the entire file, no skips as far as observable.

Things like

```
do
{
     int temp;
     temp=read(fd,buffer,MAX);
     if((temp == 0) || (temp == -1))
     {
              break;
     }
     buffer[MAX]='\0';
     write(sockfd,buffer,MAX);
     memset(buffer,NULL,MAX);
 }while(1);
```

also caused a stack overflow. Am i missing something really important here?

Thanks

Comment: What's the full actual error message you're getting at execution?

Comment: Please see my comments in the first answer. Just for the record it somehow works right now, i just seek an explanation for the work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you say that it's causing an overflow?

Do note that `read()` will not write a `\0` in the end of the `char` array, so if you do something like `printf("%s", buffer)` it will likely fail because `printf` will be expecting a NUL terminated string. You may be wanting to read `MAX-1` and set `buffer[number_of_read_characters] = '\0'` where *number_of_read_characters* is whatever `read()` returned, if positive.

Also note that when you declare `char buffer[MAX]`, since in C indexing is zero-based, the highest `buffer` index is `MAX-1`, so when you're setting `buffer[MAX]='\0'` you're already out of your array bounds.

Comment: Because I get this message in the command line
*** stack smashing detected ***:

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but this is not because of a runaway printf statement. The printf in the last line of the function is printed onto the screen. It is the return address ,etc that is geting corrupted.

Comment: then you have your answer : Miguel Ventura has explained it all : You're out of bounds with buffer[MAX]

Answer (score 1):

One problem:

```
buffer[MAX]='\0';
```

steps on stack, as the highest valid index for array of size MAX is MAX-1 (due to 0-based indexes).

-1 return value from read indicates an error, so the right thing to test read() > 0. Moreover, the normal return value from read is the number of bytes read, and read does not guarantee any 0-termination. you have to do someting along the lines of

```
while (bytesRead=read() > 0) {
    write(buffer, bytesRead);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at the code, I'd suggest that it's because the logic is different.

In the example that works, the `read(fd,buffer,MAX)` method is being executed twice.

Think of it like:

```
while (dosomething() != 0 || dosomething() != -1)
{
    // some work
}
```

This loop will be infinite if the dosomething() method is idempotent, however if the first time you run it within the while statement is different than the second, it will break.

That explains how the execution path differs, but I can't figure out why the first option overflows... I'll think about it and update. (or not - it seems it's been answered!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int fd, readCharacter;
char buffer[MAX];
while( readCharacter = read(fd, buffer, MAX**-1**) > 0 )
{
    buffer[readCharacter] = '\0';
    // ...
}
```